# How (or where) can i share sound files?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I would like to get some ideas where can one share sound files so that they are available here. I tried:

- Yourlisten.com and SoundCloud.com, but they seem to have some bugs that prevent me to operate the sites from my Fedora computer
- FreeSound.com, but they are moderated, which is ridiculous for sharing a sound here.

Are there any sites that *do work* correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Soundcloud is the site that has integrated support here to be able to post a link inline and have it turned in to a player.  It might be worth messing around with your browsers a bit to see if you can figure out why Soundcloud isn't working.

Comment: Ah thanks, it works now. I don't know what was wrong before.

Comment: Well, just you have to remove `s` from `https://` in order to activate the embedding.

Comment: It'd be nice if this was an option in the "create post", just like pictures and files.